# How to stop running task in Automation Anywhere Enterprise Client?

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

I started running process and now I can't stop it. I can't start running any other process while the first one is still running, but I can't stop it either. Tried on Esc, ctrl+alt+f4 or ctrl+alt+delete, pause and x. Does somebody have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Open task manager and kill the `AAPlayer.exe` process.